# Text show only when hover on other text

Tags: html, css

Ok so i have to display open hours. I use a Paragraph for the open hour text. When i hover on open hours it does'nt disappear and the text that it need to display is not center. Where did i go wrong?

Html:

```
<div class="heurehover">
    <p>Open hours <span class="showmeonhover">
                         blablablablablablbala </span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.showmeonhover {
    display: none;
}
.heurehover:hover .showmeonhover {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rknopy93/

Comment: You want to show "open hours" only on hover?

Comment: No, i want to show blablablablablablbala when hovering on open hours.

Comment: @VirajShah "When i hover on open hours it does'nt disappear and the text that it need to display is not center."

Comment: do you want to hide open hours and show blablabla on hover?

Comment: Yeah i want to show blablabla on hover open hours. @gp.

Comment: You have been giving us two different answers....

so on `Open Hours` once you hover, then you want `Open Hours` to disappear

Comment: and then you want `blalbaiobjioejboiajreg` to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```css
.showmeonhover { 
    display: none; 
}

.heurehover:hover .showmeonhover {
    display: inline;
}

.heurehover:hover .open {
    display: none;
}

.heurehover:hover {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="heurehover">
    <span class="open">
        Open hours
    </span>
    <span class="showmeonhover">
        blablablablablablbala
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#showmeonhover { 
    display: none; 
}


</style>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#open').hover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#showmeonhover').show();
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="heurehover">
                         <p id="open">Open hours  </p><span id="showmeonhover">
                         blablablablablablbala </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
div.heurehover span.showmeonhover:hover  {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```